# Display related products based on tags only in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, related-content

By default Woocommerce on single product page displays related products based on category - related product slider will display the same category products.

Woocommerce documentation states this - "Related Products is a section on some templates that pulls products from your store that share the same tags or categories as the current product. These products cannot be specified in the admin, but can be influenced by grouping similar products in the same category or by using the same tags."

My shop has 2 categories - "men" and "women", so this Woocommerce related product condition does not work for me. My related products should be more specific, therefore I added tags.

So - I would like to display related products based on tags only, not on categories. How can I do that?

There have been similar questions on this forum, but none of the provided codes worked, maybe because of several Woocommerce updates.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with this little hooked function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_related_product_cat_terms', 'remove_related_product_categories', 10, 2 );
function remove_related_product_categories( $terms_ids, $product_id  ){
    return array();
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

Comment: Hi what do the two numbers(10, 2) represent? Is that the category numbers? I ask because this is not working for me. Thanks

Comment: @Soulipsyz see documentation [**Wordpress `add_filter()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)…

Comment: This solution (tested on WooCommerce 6.7.0) and all the solutions similar to it do work, but the change often won't take place immediately. To see the changes, you need to delete the transients.